# ASP.NET calendar client mode

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have to display a calendar control on a web page. The main requirement is to call a certain javascript function when user selects any date.

The asp.net server control postsback and i dont want a postback. So my question is it possible to run the calendar control in client mode i.e no postback and attach javascript function to each date passing in the selected date value.

I tried to use jQuery date picker but the graphics layout of my page messes the layout.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the ASP.NET AJAX CalendarExtender? If so, can you make use of the OnClientDateSelectionChanged event?

If my memory serves me correctly, that would allow you to define a javascript function and get the user's selection without triggering a postback.

Comment: i wasnt planning on using the ajax calendarextender, i thought there could be issues with jQuery?

Comment: I've used it on pages before that had jQuery elements as well. But I guess it would depend on how intensive you're going with jQuery. Many people will say that a jQuery calendar is the way to go though. I'm not really for or against either one, but that's probably just my inexperience with jQuery talking.

Comment: i agree, i just cant get the styling right. my CSS messes up the jQuery calendars styling

Comment: Which jQuery calendar are you using? If you hit F12 in either IE9/IE10 or Chrome (I'm sure it works on Firefox too, never tried), you can use the developer tools to inspect the CSS and see exactly where the conflict is.

Comment: Also, if you're using jQuery everywhere else, the .NET AJAX calendar is probably not the way to go. Like I said, depends on what you're doing with the page, and how far you go with the JavaScript.